# How to register Google Maps API key for a client's domain I don't own?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, clientid

I have a website I developed for a client. One of the pages displays a list of street addresses, for which I also have LAT/LONG data. The client requested to add a little map next to this list with a marker for each address.
I would like to use Google Maps API v3, but I have a problem registering client's internet facing URL, which has a form of "ip address:port" (i.e. something like `http://123.45.67.89:555`) and which I - naturally - do not own and do not have domain admin access. Likewise, their domain admin - whoever s/he is - does not and will not have access to my Google API project for which I'm trying to register the key.

So far I was able to register the client id for local development in a form of `http://localhost:5555`, but when I'm trying to add the client's URL I'm getting an error

```
OAuth 2 redirect URL "http://123.45.67.89:555" is invalid.
```

I searched for solution for this problem and found a suggestion to whitelist the URL in the Google API Console. Yet when I'm trying to add this URL to approved domain list ("notification endpoints") I'm only getting another error:

```
You do not have access to the following domain: 
http://123.45.67.89:555
```

which is, of course, true. The documentation also says I cannot register a domain I don't own.

So, my question is: **how do I register a Client ID for Google Maps API V3 for the client's URL to which I don't have domain admin privileges and whose domain admin doesn't have access to my API project?**

### Thank you!

*Nikolai*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view of the table (File | Create View ...) and own the view (https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171206?hl=en) - thus enabling you to have your own version of the table which is in sync with changes.

As a footnote remember to deal with Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in your API project by using JSONP for example (https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin).

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Google Maps API v3, there is no need to use Google API Key. Simply use below script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: this is an outdated answer. From June 11. 2018 on every request to the google maps api will need an api key: [Google User Guide](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/)